# replace all symbols and white spaces with dash using htaccess rewrite

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url

I want to rewrite the URL by replacing spaces and other symbols with dash and removing apostrophe. I am unable to do it. Here is my `.htaccess`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^videos/([0-9]+)/([a-z\-A-Z]+) post.php?p_id=$1&title=$2 [L]
```

Example

Result: `example.com/videos/1/why's%20%sis%sare`

Expected: `example.com/videos/1/whys-20-is-are`

Comment: always add some example of how its suposed to work

Comment: @MaciejKozieja add supposed to work

Comment: try using [rawurlencode](http://php.net/rawurlencode) function

Comment: @MaciejKozieja it just returns the spaces with %20

Comment: @MaciejKozieja but how can I use it in rewrite

Comment: try this: RewriteRule ^videos/([0-9]+)/(([a-zA-Z][\-])*) post.php?p_id=$1&title=$2 [L]